# Docker compose: using relative service address in environment

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile

For example, I defined two services in my `docker-compose`

```
  backend:
    env_file:
      - .env.backend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8686:8686"
  frontend:
    env_file:
    - .env.front_end
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

In frontend app, I defined environment with this endpoint:

```
BACKEND_ENDPOINT=http://www.backend.com/api/v1/backend/
```

The problem I don't know how to solve here is: how can I convert above endpoint to relative endpoint based on backend service. For example, if you run only backend under localhost, url should be: `localhost:8686/api/v1/backend`. So the url of backend in above docker-compose file should be: `[backend_address]:8686/api/v1/backend`. So how can I map address and port automatically here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With `docker-compose`, all services are always resolvable by their names.

In your example, you should add a `depends_on` from your frontend to your backend, and simply use the name `backend` to address the backend server.

```
frontend:
  depends_on:
    - 'backend'
```

The frontend should be able to resolve the backend at `backend:8086`. Note that the `depends_on` isn't required for name resolution, but it *is* required to ensure that the port is open when your `frontend` container is created.

Comment: so my endpoint will be: `backend:8086/api/v1/backend` ? If this true, what is the url when backend means "backend". thanks.